# FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, large-data

I have an array of size 10000. All those are document ids. I am running an array and need to get the document data from Firestore and need to add the new fields in each document. But I am facing the below errors like

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.3.1): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.3.1): Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.

Error getting document: FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
    at new t (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:61679)
    at Object.next (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:308843)
    at next (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:308006)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:277502
```

Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: I think you are running on the issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107889/what-is-the-exact-size-of-a-firestore-document). I also personally run in the same problem and wrote to the Firebase team. They said it's a problem when storing large amounts of data in arrays. They'll fix it out at a future update.

Comment: @AlexMamo Are there any news? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @Mibit Did not test again. Give it a try and see if it works. Maybe also wrote an answer.

Comment: now in 2022 i run in the same problem ,

Comment: What does the firebase team define as 'large amount of data in arrays' - when you run into these issues?