# Some resource has been exhausted, perhaps a per-user quota, or perhaps the entire file system is out of space

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

always when i store, write `.get()` , `update()`large data , up to 1000 docs i face this message error from `Firstore`

Some resource has been exhausted, perhaps a per-user quota, or perhaps the entire file system is out of space

Note: i have paid plan in `Firstore` however i get this error message

this happen while i still testing my app with some thousand of docs as one user .
i am asking my self what if there was hundred of users in my app !!!!!!!

i have read the same issue here m this question was written in 10 months a go ,

[FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61476809/firebaseerror-code-resource-exhausted-resource-has-been-exhausted-e-g-chec)

and the following was the useful comment by Alex Mamo

> I think you are running on the issue as here. I also personally run in the same problem and wrote to the Firebase team. They said it's a problem when storing large amounts of data in arrays. They'll fix it out at a future update. –
> Alex Mamo
> Apr 28, 2020 at 9:36

i tried to deeply search into this issue but cannot understand if it really the maximum limit of data operation by `Firstore`

I am not exaggerating if I say sometimes I receive this error message with up to 800 bonds as well
and after this error message all Firebase products  stopped , auth , get , set etc ..

Now i can't login into my app since 3 days and that's happen after two huge operation around 1000 docs .. the same error message

anyone could tell me what's going on here guys ?
thanks

Comment: Hey Jack. I think it's best if you write directly to the Firebase team.

Comment: Hello Alex Mamo , thanks for comment , i will write them