# Firebase resource exhausted (e.g. check quota) on blaze plan

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I am using a `Firestore` within  `Vue` app.

Firestore works fine when the load is is not high

**but**, when I try to request around ~10k (in total) records from ~10 different collections like this:

```
 for (const module in dynamicModules) {
        Vue.set(state, module, []);
        bindFirestoreRef(module, db.collection(
          "tenants/" + store.state.tenantID + "/modules/" + module +
          "/records")).then(() => {
            const m = module;
        });
      }
```

**Sometimes** (not reproducable), I receive the following error:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.19.0): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.19.0): Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

I've seen [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61476809/firebaseerror-code-resource-exhausted-resource-has-been-exhausted-e-g-chec?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107889/what-is-the-exact-size-of-a-firestore-document) topic but they don't provide an answer to the problem

I'm on the blaze plan so as far as I can see there should not be a read quota

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: To move this forward to be able to reproduce your scenario, can you please provide an image of your data structure? To investigate a common issue, have you always had this issue? If not, when did it start?

Comment: Sure: [image](https://i.imgur.com/pBuHAah.png). 
Structure is very easy but nested:
/tenants/{tenant}/modules/{module}/records/{records} 
where an average tenant has 10 modules and around 2k records in each module collection.
I did not always had this issue, it started a few weeks ago and it might have something to do with the fact that the record size is growing per record collection.

Comment: I suspect the issue may be quota related. What billing plan are you using?

Comment: As mentioned in the title and question i'm on the blaze plan with no additional quotas set up. So it should have nothing to do with a quota, because if you wait 5 min and try again it might be working perfectly.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. I'd like to search for a common issue related to your error. Can you provide a timestamp and time zone when this last occurred?

Comment: No worries, glad that you are willing to help.
Most recent one is : 2020-11-12T08:26:13.577Z in GMT + 1 

And by the way,  i've enabled synchronizeTabs in the PersistenceSettings [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.PersistenceSettings) since a few days and it seems to be more stable now. I can now easily reproduce the error when I go in chrome too: Inspect Element > Application > Clear Site data and refresh the page. I do this 3/4 times the error will pop up.

Comment: Hello. I'm happy you have found the information. The best way to move forward, since you are reporting a bug, is to use the link (https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) to have this addressed. I will wait for your response.

Comment: I've created a bug report!

Comment: @Jobias did you ever get more information after submitting your bug report? Do you have a link to the report you can share?

Comment: @Brandon, nope never. Was asked a lot of non sense questions, eventually I gave up .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use values change listener  instead of Query . It will help , Store these values changes data in your local cache.

Comment: This is a workaround and doesn't work for me. I need to do some complex queries and Firestore query capabilities are too limited for my use case